# How to create transparent icon using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to create icons (`.ico` format) with ImageMagick with only partial success. I can't get the resulting icon to have any transparency. I've tried many things like `-alpha Background`, `-quantize transparent`, `-transparent-color`, but I just can't get it working.

I can get it working if I don't reduce the colors `-colors 256`. It's with that reduction where I lose the transparency.

How do you produce a transparent icon with image magick (`convert`)?

Answer (score -1):

I generate transparent PNGs with the [`-alpha transparent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#alpha) option.  For example:

```
convert -size 100x100 -alpha transparent \
  -stroke black -strokewidth 5 -fill blue \
  -draw "rectangle 20,20,80,80" \
   xc:#990000 test.png
```

This creates `test.png` with a floating blue box with a black border, inside an image with a transparent background.  It uses a block colour as the "input" image , but the red is obliterated by the full transparency of its channel.

[image: generated image with alpha]

If you remove the alpha, you'll see the red source image.

[image: generated image with no alpha]

Comment: Okay, well, change the `.png` to `.ico`, and `convert` will generate the different format based on the extension.

Comment: But that's what doesn't work. I do color reduction `-colors 256` and output to icon and it isn't transparent.

Comment: I don't have enough information to reproduce the problem you're having.  When I add `-colors 256` to my command line, it *does* leave the background transparent.  Perhaps you'd [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22524231/1072112) with additional detail?

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem when trying to generate a transparent favicon from transparent PNGs. Here's what worked for me:

`convert transparent-img1.png transparent-img2.png transparent-img3.png -channel Alpha favicon.ico`